# Olympic Medals Points system, 3 for Gold, 2 for Silver, 1 for Bronze

Tags: python

Write a function that creates a Series called "Points" which is a weighted value where each gold medal (`Gold.2`) counts for 3 points, silver medals (`Silver.2`) for 2 points, and bronze medals (`Bronze.2`) for 1 point. The function should return only the column (a Series object) which you created.

*This function should return a Series named `Points` of length 146*

I'm new to python and pandas and I don't know if I'm on the right track or not with this code but I'm getting a key error

```
KeyError: "['Gold.2' 'Silver.2' 'Bronze.2'] not in index" for this code: 

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv', index_col=0, skiprows=1)

def answer_four():

    df['Points'] = df[(df[['Gold.2','Silver.2','Bronze.2']], [3,2,1])]
    #df[['Gold.2','Silver.2','Bronze.2']].apply(lambda x:(x,[3,2,1]))
    olympic_points_df = df[['Points']]


    return olympic_points_df

answer_four()
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: So...this statement... `df['Points'] = df[(df[['Gold.2','Silver.2','Bronze.2']], [3,2,1])]` ...what on Earth are you actually trying to assign to `df['Points']` here???

Comment: Normally you sort gold first, then silver, then bronze. 2 gold will always be worth more than 1 gold+12 silver.

Answer (score 2):

Some similar to this would do the trick

```
def answer_four():
    df['Points'] = df['Gold.2']*3 + df['Silver.2']*2 + df['Bronze.2'] 
    return df['Points']
```

Comment: When I try something like that I get                                                          KeyError: 'Gold.2''       How would I get that fixed?

Comment: If you got a key error only in 'Gold.2', the problem should definitely be in that key, check spell, ' ', etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
def answer_four():
    df['Points'] = df['Gold.2']*3 + df['Silver.2']*2 + df['Bronze.2']
    Points = pd.Series(df['Points'],index=df.index)
    return Points

answer_four()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by checking the column names, and if necessary, do some renaming:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('olympics.csv',
                 index_col=0,
                 skiprows=1
                )

for col in df.columns:
    if 'gold' in col.lower():
        print(col)
        # and maybe perform a rename if needed: 
        # df.rename(columns={col:'Gold'+'.2'},
        #           inplace=True)


def answer_four():
    df['Points'] = pd.Series((df['Gold.2']*3) + (df['Silver.2']*2) + df['Bronze.2'])
    return df['Points']


answer_four()
```